# Unable to compile jsp on server

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

when i run my jsp at local host it works fine but when i run at server it show me the error.
I have post the error below. Please help me out.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/UploadFile/org/apache/jsp/Jsp/ReviewQuestions_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. javax.websocket.Session resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "run at local host" and "run on server"? Can you provide jsp code?

Comment: Have you set the JSP compilation switch fork to false ?

Comment: at local host means when i run at Eclipse and run on server means deployed on server.

Comment: I am posting the code here .

Comment: Luigi Cortese, I am saying that when i run this Jsp file on my localhost using eclipse. it works completely fine. but when i deploy my project on online server then this Jsp file gives a error.

Comment: Are you using tomcat 7 or above as server ?

Comment: salil , No i have not done anything like that.

Comment: Ok, got it! Are you using the same server in local and remote?

Comment: Naveen, i am using tomcat

Comment: Luigi, Yes i am using tomcat 7

Comment: from exception it looks like your are using websocket but probably you will required tomcat 8 from this because tomcat docs says "Tomcat's Java WebSocket 1.0 (JSR-356) implementation is currently only available in Tomcat 8", Just try on tomcat 8 as web container.

Comment: Naveen , I am not using websocket i am using javax.servlet.http.HttpSession, I don't knw why it is showing the websocket even i have imported the javax.websocket.Session but still the error is same.